# Scraping from yahoo finance with beautifulsoup resulting in status code : 404

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, yahoo-finance

I am trying to scrape some data from yahoo finance using beautifulsoup, but I've run into a problem. I am trying to run the following code,

```
import xlwings as xw
import requests
import bs4 as bs

r = requests.get('https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/DKK=X?p=DKK=X&.tsrc=fin-srch')
soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(r.content,'lxml',from_encoding='utf-8')
```

However, when inspecting my output from "soup", I get the following status code in the  section,

```
<body>
<!-- status code : 404 -->
<!-- Not Found on Server -->
```

I've run the exact same piece of code on another trading pair on yahoo finance with no problem whatsoever.
Could anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to inject user agent to get 200 response.

```
#import xlwings as xw
import requests
import bs4 as bs

headers={'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/98.0.4758.102 Safari/537.36'}
r = requests.get('https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/DKK=X?p=DKK=X&.tsrc=fin-srch',headers=headers)
print(r)
soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(r.content,'lxml')
```

Output:
<Response [200]>