# using yahoo! finance to get prior earnings dates for last 5 years for a given stock

Tags: python, yahoo-finance

Trying to get 1) earnings dates for the last 5 years for a given stock
(TGT) along with 2) the accompanying price percentage change on those days. Then put data in a dataframe

This is the code I have found to use so far but it seems that the error comes from the date range. It seems that in this instance, yahoo! finance makes you put specific dates and times in for a date range which is not ideal. What would be better is just have some generally delineated 5 year range etc. if any folks would know how to do that.  thanks much!

```
import datetime
from yahoo_earnings_calendar import YahooEarningsCalendar

date_from = datetime.datetime.strptime(
    'Jan 1 2017  10:00AM', '%b %d %Y %I:%M%p')
date_to = datetime.datetime.strptime(
    'Jan 1 2022  1:00PM', '%b %d %Y %I:%M%p')
yec = YahooEarningsCalendar()
# print(yec.earnings_on(date_from))
# print(yec.earnings_between(date_from, date_to))

print(yec.get_earnings_of('tgt'))

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
~\anaconda3\envs\fintech\lib\site-packages\yahoo_earnings_calendar\scraper.py in get_earnings_of(self, symbol)
    153         try:
--> 154             page_data_dict = self._get_data_dict(url)
    155             return page_data_dict["context"]["dispatcher"]["stores"]["ScreenerResultsStore"]["results"]["rows"]

~\anaconda3\envs\fintech\lib\site-packages\yahoo_earnings_calendar\scraper.py in _get_data_dict(self, url)
     37         page_content = page.content.decode(encoding='utf-8', errors='strict')
---> 38         page_data_string = [row for row in page_content.split(
     39             '\n') if row.startswith('root.App.main = ')][0][:-1]

IndexError: list index out of range

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Exception                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-40-7c9d8ed0a796> in <module>
      1 # print(yec.get_earnings_date('tgt'))
----> 2 print(yec.get_earnings_of('tgt'))

~\anaconda3\envs\fintech\lib\site-packages\yahoo_earnings_calendar\scraper.py in get_earnings_of(self, symbol)
    155             return page_data_dict["context"]["dispatcher"]["stores"]["ScreenerResultsStore"]["results"]["rows"]
    156         except:
--> 157             raise Exception('Invalid Symbol or Unavailable Earnings Date')
    158 
    159 if __name__ == '__main__':  # pragma: no cover

Exception: Invalid Symbol or Unavailable Earnings Date
```

Comment: Looks to me that this API is no longer active, but I could be wrong. If I'm right, you could use the yfinance API instead.

Answer (score 1):

The `YahooEarningsCalendar` is no longer actively maintained with the latest commit dating back to 2020.

Looking at [the code](https://github.com/wenboyu2/yahoo-earnings-calendar/blob/master/yahoo_earnings_calendar/scraper.py) an error is thrown whenever the scraped result does not match an expected site structure. Several [open issues](https://github.com/wenboyu2/yahoo-earnings-calendar) exist regarding the missing `User-Agents` in the request, which are now required for scraping the yahoo finance web page (see e.g. [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71207430/scraping-from-yahoo-finance-with-beautifulsoup-resulting-in-status-code-404)). Hence, the site structure is not matched.

Unfortunately, you can not set this agent manually through the API. I'd suggest using `yahoo_fin` as a drop-in replacement.

Your code would look like this.

```
import yahoo_fin.stock_info as si

# alternative 1
ticker_earnings = si.get_earnings('TGT')
# alternative 2
earnings_in_range = si.get_earnings_in_date_range('2017-01-01','2022-01-01')
```

Comment: in alternative 2 - where are you inserting the ticker, TGT?  thx much

Comment: @new2coding You do not. The function will return all the stock tickers with expected EPS data for all dates in the input range. Note, that dates aren't accounted for in your code either.

Comment: ok where would I put the TGT ticker in "alt 2" so I am only getting earnings results for TGT for those 5 years? Thx much!

Comment: @new2coding You can not set the ticker in alt 2. (see docs) You'd have to select ticker from result set, which is a list of dicts.

Answer (score 0):

```
import yfinance as yf
import pandas as pd
stock = yf.Ticker('TGT')
df = stock.quarterly_earnings
or
df = stock.earnings
```

Will do the trick, pandas is only used to get the data in a dataframe, which makes it nicer to save to csv or sql for instance.

Comment: Does not work for me: yfinance.exceptions.YFNotImplementedError: Have not implemented fetching 'earnings' from Yahoo API